# Illegal character in URL

Tags: java, url, get

I get an error "`Illegal character in URL`" in my code and I don't know why:
I have a token and an hash that are string type.

```
String currentURL = "http://platform.shopyourway.com" +
                    "/products/get-by-tag?tagId=220431" +
                    "&token=" + token +
                    "&hash=" + hash;
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {

     URL url = new URL(currentURL);
     urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
     urlConnection.connect();

[...]
```

but when I wrote :

```
URL url = new URL("http://platform.shopyourway.com/products/get-by-tag?tagId=220431&token=0_11800_253402300799_1_a9c1d19702ed3a5e873fd3b3bcae6f8e3f8b845c9686418768291042ad5709f1&hash=e68e41e4ea4ed16f4dbfb32668ed02b080bf1f2cbee64c2692ef510e7f7dc26b");
```

it's work, but I can't write this order because I don't know the hash and the token because I generate them every time. 
thanks.

Comment: Use [URLEncoder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding) on your values

Comment: what's in variables `token` and `hash`?

Comment: So, print the value of the hash and the value of the token, and find which character is illegal. And ure-encode them if you really need that illegal character: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: example: 
String token ="0_11825_1415294906_2_b81903a2c188992baf532183c49621df010f94f10859b261ee1fa0d2bcfcabcf"

Comment: Doesn't the exception tell you where?

Comment: URLEncoder works fine ! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the [Oracle docs on creating URLs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/creatingUrls.html) you need to escape the "values" of your URL string.

> **URL addresses with Special characters**
>
> Some URL addresses contain special characters, for example the space
>   character. Like this:
>
> http://example.com/hello world/ To make these characters legal they
>   need to be encoded before passing them to the URL constructor.
>
> `URL url = new URL("http://example.com/hello%20world");`
>
> Encoding the special character(s) in this example is easy as there is
>   only one character that needs encoding, but for URL addresses that
>   have several of these characters or if you are unsure when writing
>   your code what URL addresses you will need to access, you can use the
>   multi-argument constructors of the java.net.URI class to automatically
>   take care of the encoding for you.
>
> `URI uri = new URI("http", "example.com", "/hello world/", "");`
>
> And then convert the URI to a URL.
>
> `URL url = uri.toURL();`

As commented also [see this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding) that uses URLEncoder to replace any offending characters